# Calculate Fourier coefficients of a product

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I've stumbled across the following problem when studying about Fourier Analysis and are very interested in the solution:

For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $P$ a trigonometric polynomial of degree $N>0$ on $\mathbb{T}$, find calculate the Fourier coefficients of the product $fP$ in terms of those of $f$ and $P$.

Now, what I've tried is computing $\widehat{fP}$ by the following:

\begin{equation}
\widehat{fP}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)P(x)e^{-inx}dx
\end{equation}

From here, I tried substituting $P(x)=\sum_{m=-N}^{N}c_me^{im x}$ and by changing integral and sum I got

\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=-N}^{N}c_m\widehat{f}(n-m)
\end{equation}

Now, I'm already doubting whether my answer is correct or not, but if it were correct, how does this representation represent the Fourier coefficients of $P$ at all?

I look forward to any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you got is correct. Calculate the Fourier coefficients of P, and see how they relate to the $c_m$'s. (Btw this question is oddly familiar to me, do you happen to be a student at TU Delft?)

Comment: I see, I've computed the $\widehat{P}$ and found out they were exactly $c_m$ as long as $-N<m<N$. So is it correct to say that $\widehat{fP}(n)=\sum_{m=-N}^{N}\widehat{f}(n-m)\cdot \widehat{P}(m)$ ? And BTW, yes I do study there!

Comment: Yep that is correct. Good luck with the exam next week ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll still be posting questions about this topic if you don't mind :)